# Visual Basic PictureBox

Tags: vb.net

**A description of my game:**

When you start the game, you have a few seconds to memorize the arrangement of the grids. By the arrangement, I mean each grid is one of two colors. After the time is up, all the grids are set to the 'off' color. The player must click on the grids to toggle them and put them in their correct color assignments as they were seen before.

**Okay so this is part of a game I am developing.Instead of using solid colors, I want use background images but I don't know how to edit the code to do so. Any help would be welcome.**

```
    Dim GridOn As Color = Color.LightBlue
    Dim GridOff As Color = Color.DarkBlue
    Dim MaxTime As Integer = 40

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For Each pic As Control In Me.Controls 'For every picture in form1's controls...
            If TypeOf pic Is PictureBox Then   'Then, only picks the pictureboxes, not the buttons, labels, etc.
                AddHandler pic.Click, AddressOf PictureBoxClick 'For each picturebox (grid), add an event handler (PictureBoxClick) to avoid
            End If                                              'typing 16 of them ourselves
        Next
    End Sub

        Private Sub PictureBoxClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        If AllowEdit = True Then
            Dim ctrl As PictureBox = DirectCast(sender, Control)
            If ctrl.BackColor = GridOn Then
                ctrl.BackColor = GridOff 'Set the backcolor to either GridOn or GridOff
            Else : ctrl.BackColor = GridOn
            End If
        Else
            'Do not allow the user to change the colors
        End If
      End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: PictureBox has an Image property.  Is that the issue?

Comment: picturebox.imageLoaction = "Directory"  instead picturebox.backcolor

Comment: Thank you. But I am still confuse about how to do the comparison, ctrl = gridOn , comparing an image to an image , we can't do that right ?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question fully...

picturebox.imageLoaction = "Directory" instead of picturebox.backcolor

FOR THE CONIDTIONING TRY,

One work-around is to store an integer constant, or string constant into the Tag field of the picturebox to identify the image you placed in the picturebox. e.g.

```
pbo1.Tag = "Ice Cream"
' or
pbo1.Tag = IMAGE.icecream
' where
Enum IMAGE
    ICE CREAM
    CHERRY
    ' etc....
End Enum
```